# Сортировка по возрастанию суммы значений

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, как составить запрос чтобы в нем производилась сортировка по сумме двух полей, например:

```sql
SELECT "name","prais1","prais2" FROM "tovari",
```

Мне нужно чтобы в запросе была сортировка по возрастанию `prais1+prais2`

Comment: закрывайте вопрос

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT name, paris1, paris2, (paris1+paris2) as paris 
FROM `tovari` ORDER BY paris
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT name, prais1, parais2, SUM(prais1 + parais2) as myfield
FROM tovati
ORDER BY myfield
```

Comment: Одновременно)))

Comment: а верен ли ответ? )

Comment: Наверное, еще не проверили)

Comment: Под рукой нет базы просто.
Попробуй добавить GROUP BY 

SELECT name, prais1, parais2, SUM(prais1 + parais2) as myfield
FROM tovati
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY myfield