# Сортировка по сумме двух полей?

Tags: mysql, sql

В таблице 1 есть поле view. - число просмотров записи.
Имеется связь с таблице 2, в которой содержатся все ответы к записям из таблицы 1. Связь один ко многим.
Как вывести все записи из таблицы 1 отсортированные по количеству просмотров в сумме с количеством ответов к каждой записи?
Что-то вроде этого:

```
SELECT a.* COUNT(d.idAnswerToQuestion) + a.view AS answers FROM questions a LEFT JOIN answers d ON ....
```

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот похожий вопрос: [Сортировка по возрастанию суммы значений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26256/mysql-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

```
SELECT name, paris1, paris2, (paris1+paris2) as paris FROM `tovari` ORDER BY paris
```